# I am getting an "Implicit conversion from enumeration type" warning in Xcode for iOS and I don't know why

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

With this code:

```
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink
                                                               error:&error];
```

I am getting this warning:

```
Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum NSTextCheckingType' to different enumeration type 'NSTextCheckingTypes' (aka 'enum NSTextCheckingTypes')
```

Can someone explain to me why I am getting this warning and how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`+dataDetectorWithTypes:` does claim to take a value from the NSTextCheckingTypes enum rather than NSTextCheckingType, but going by the rest of its documentation it should indeed allow you to specify individual values from the latter enum. I would just add a cast to NSTextCheckingTypes. You might also want to [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) on the API.

Comment: I think this is a fallout from using enums with a fixed underlying type. `NSTextCheckingTypes` used to just be a typedef for `uint64_t`, but it's now actually a typedef for `enum NSTextCheckingTypes : uint64_t`.

Comment: It looks like a bug in the declaration for `+dataDetectorWithTypes:`. It's declared to take `NSTextCheckingTypes` (with an 's'), but it looks like it should in fact take `NSTextCheckingType`. File a bug and  then use `#pragma`s to disable the warning on this line, and then make a note to recheck this code every release until you can remove the `#pragma`s.

Comment: I'm not sure using a cast is the right way to temporarily silence this warning, although it does have the benefit that when the API is fixed it would start warning again.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the docs for this method. The first parameter needs to be of type `NSTextCheckingTypes`. But the value you pass in, `NSTextCheckingTypeLink`, is of type `NSTextCheckingType`.

You need to pass in either `NSTextCheckingAllSystemTypes`, `NSTextCheckingAllCustomTypes`, or `NSTextCheckingAllTypes`.

Edit:

Upon further review, while what I stated seems correct from a parameter point of view, the rest of the docs for the method claim something else that contradicts the parameter type. Either something changed or this is a bug. Someone should report this to Apple.

Further edit:

One workaround would be to make use of a cast:

```
NSDataDetector *detector = 
    [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:(NSTextCheckingTypes)NSTextCheckingTypeLink
    error:&error];
```

Comment: Not quite accurate—the documentation for NSDataDetector specifies that, e.g., `NSTextCheckingTypeLink` is valid on its own.

Comment: I was just noticing that. Something isn't right here. The docs are really misleading on this.

Comment: For this question :
I am getting an “Implicit conversion from enumeration type” warning in Xcode for iOS and I don't know why

This is the correct answer :
NSDataDetector *detector = 
    [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:(NSTextCheckingTypes)NSTextCheckingTypeLink
    error:&error];

I had same problem, by using above line of code worked perfectly for me. The issue is we were facing because of Type Casting only.. :)

Thanks for the Answer @rmaddy +1 for you